# How do I activate datepicker widget on custom form field?

Tags: python, flask, datepicker, flask-admin

For example, when I add custom ModelView:

```
class TaskModelView(ModelView):
    pass


flaskadmin = Admin(name='Flasky', template_mode='bootstrap3', index_view=MyAdminIndexView(),
                   base_template='admin/mymaster.html')

flaskadmin.add_views(TaskModelView(models.Task, db.session))
```

I also get useful datepicker widget on appropriate DateTime fields:
[image]

But what about custom views and forms? I tried to add view same way, but inherited it from BaseView, then I created new form with DateTimeField from flask-admin and tried to render it:

```
from flask.ext.admin.form import DateTimeField, DatePickerWidget, DateTimePickerWidget


class AssebledChartForm(Form):
    date_from = DateTimeField('From', format='%d.%m.%Y', widget=DateTimePickerWidget())
    date_to = DateTimeField('To')


class AnalyticsView(BaseView):
<...>
    return self.render('admin/analytic.html', form=form)

flaskadmin.add_view(AnalyticsView(name='Analytics', endpoint='analytics'))
```

but widget did not appear both on `from` and `to` fields:
[image]

How do I use flask-admin datepicker on my own forms?

Answer (score 2):

You have to `import DateTimePickerWidget` like this:

`from flask_admin.form import DateTimePickerWidget`

and use it, for example, like this:

```
start = DateTimeField('Start', widget=DateTimePickerWidget())
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you can use either jQuery datepicker for this, or WTForms one, and not a `flask.ext.admin.form`.

Admin form is intended to be hidden from the end user, and exposing its API to the public user is strongly prohibited.

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057710/datepickerwidget-with-flask-flask-admin-and-wtforms)

And you can see a good example on how to use WTForms DatePicker.

Comment: admin.form just provides a number of fields to use to create admin interface, and DateTimeField is one of them. It is also inherited from WTForms DateTimeField to use Flask-admin DataTimeWidget. What i'm looking for is how to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your admin/analytic.html is not loading the javascript that handles the client side selection of dates. add the following to your template;

```
{% block tail_js %}
     <script src="/static/vendor/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
     {# use /static/bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js if you are using bootstrap2 #}
     <script src="/static/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/static/vendor/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/static/vendor/select2/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

This should give you everything you need to make all the widgets work (Select2, DatePicker, etc).