# 2 Datepicker in FlaskForm

Tags: python, flask

I found this on [DatePickerWidget with Flask, Flask-Admin and WTforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057710/datepickerwidget-with-flask-flask-admin-and-wtforms) and this is perfect but I need two datepickers because I want to pickup 2 date (start and end date) for SQL query

py file:

```
class ExampleForm(Form):
    dt = DateField('DatePicker', format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

and here I assign to variable:

```
date = form.dt.data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

html file:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {{ form.dt(class='datepickerA') }}
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <input type="submit"/>
```

I'm not sure how to add one more picker and assign to 2 variable in py file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to install **flask.ext.admin.form** but pip did not find it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ExampleForm` class needs to have two members:

```
class ExampleForm(Form):
    dStart = DateField(...)
    dEnd = DateField(...)
```

Then in your form, you would use something like this:

```
<form action="/process" method="POST">
    {{ form.dStart.label }} {{ form.dStart() }}
    {{ form.dEnd.label }} {{ form.dEnd() }}
    <input type="submit">Do it!</input>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks a lot for this. I just added this after second datepicker
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}